# everyauth password example error

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, everyauth

I followed the installation for everyauth, according to their guide:
http://everyauth.com/#installation

I'm trying to run the Password example,
but after I run the server, and to go localhost:3000 in the browser I get this error:

```
    Error: \workspace\test\node_modules\everyauth\example\views\home.jade:102
    100|       label(for='openid_identifier') OpenID Identifier: &nbsp;
    101|       input(type='text', name='openid_identifier')
  &gt; 102|       input(type='submit') Login
    103| - else
    104|   h2 Authenticated
    105|   - if (everyauth.facebook)

input is self closing and should not have content.
    at Object.Compiler.visitTag (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:455:32)
    at Object.Compiler.visitNode (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:222:37)
    at Object.Compiler.visit (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:209:10)
    at Object.Compiler.visitBlock (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:292:12)
    at Object.Compiler.visitNode (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:222:37)
    at Object.Compiler.visit (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:209:10)
    at Object.Compiler.visitTag (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:464:12)
    at Object.Compiler.visitNode (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:222:37)
    at Object.Compiler.visit (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:209:10)
    at Object.Compiler.visitBlock (\workspace\test\node_modules\jade\lib\compiler.js:292:12)
```

Did anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a jade issue, not an everyauth issue.

**Solution:**
Change:

```
102|       input(type='submit') Login
```

To:

```
102|       input(type='submit',value='Login')
```

**Reference Links:**

1. [input tag docs, showing the tag is a void (self-closing) element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)
2. [Jade docs on tags, self-closing](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#tags)
3. [Jade attribute examples](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#attributes)
4. [input is self closing and should not have content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743374/input-is-self-closing-and-should-not-have-content)
5. [error: input is self closing and should not have content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811379/error-input-is-self-closing-and-should-not-have-content)